# Liferay SDK for autocomplete feature renders cached data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, liferay, liferay-aui

Hi I am using liferay SDK for autocomplete feature. But once I click on submit and return to autocomplete search box, it renders the cached value also. Could some one help me in removing this cache since it is hiding other data behind it in the list. here is the code sample:

`AUI().use('autocomplete-list','aui-base','aui-io-request','autocomplete-filters','autocomplete-highlighters',function (A) {
        A.io.request('<%=autoCompleteCompanyName.toString()%>',{
            dataType: 'json',
            method: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            on: {
                success: function() {
                    new A.AutoCompleteList({
                    allowBrowserAutocomplete: 'false',
                    activateFirstItem: 'false',
                    inputNode: '#<portlet:namespace/>companyName',
                    resultTextLocator: 'companyName',
                    resultHighlighter:['phraseMatch'],
                    resultFilters:['phraseMatch'],
                    maxResults:100,
                    render: 'true',
                    autoLoad:false,
                    source:this.get('responseData'),
                    });
                   }
                }
        });`

[image]